# Mapbox Android SDK Track device location always crash

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I tried to implement the source code that available at https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-change-listening/ and I almost copy all the code to see the behavior but the application keeps crashing. Sometimes, it crashes pretty much immediately and sometimes, it works fine for a couple of minutes then crash.

This is the error log that i got from the Logcat that always appear whenever the application crash

```
2020-12-15 12:40:33.989 2648-15681/com.vathere.locationtracker A/libc: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r20/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating" failed
2020-12-15 12:40:33.994 2648-15681/com.vathere.locationtracker A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 15681 (Worker 1), pid 2648 (ndata.jelantara)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.093 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-12-15 12:40:34.093 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:9/PSR1.180720.117/5875966:user/release-keys'
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: pid: 2648, tid: 15681, name: Worker 1  >>> com.vathere.locationtracker <<<
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r20/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating" failed'
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00000a58  ecx 00003d41  edx 00000006
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     edi 00000a58  esi 00000000
2020-12-15 12:40:34.094 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     ebp cd4ff154  esp cd4ff0e8  eip ece0cb39
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000b39  [vdso:ece0c000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00022ed3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00023388  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+56)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0031fa14  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0031fab8  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0031cd09  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0031cc51  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so (std::terminate()+65)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0031b6d8  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so (std::__ndk1::thread::~thread()+40)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000af3d7  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000af343  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 002c9863  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00311b8f  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0004cac5  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00137138  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00137171  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00092109  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00311b8f  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 0004cac5  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 001376f6  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 0005096b  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 00172478  /data/app/com.vathere.locationtracker-rbj3IuoJfUBBzXi_-pCgdw==/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 0008f065  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.096 15694-15694/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 0002485b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
2020-12-15 12:40:34.725 1789-1789/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
2020-12-15 12:40:34.782 1927-1997/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '74c4bde com.vathere.locationtracker/com.vathere.locationtracker.ActivityMapNew (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2020-12-15 12:40:34.783 1927-1997/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8eceb82 com.vathere.locationtracker/com.vathere.locationtracker.ActivityLoading (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

The code I implement

```
package com.vathere.locationtracker;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineCallback;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineResult;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponentActivationOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.RenderMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.List;

public class ActivityMapNew extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

    Context context;

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mbMap;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private static final long DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000L;
    private static final long DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME = DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS * 5;

    private ActivityMapNew.LocationCallback callback = new ActivityMapNew.LocationCallback(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_new);

        context = getBaseContext();

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        mbMap = mapboxMap;

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.SATELLITE_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                enableLocationComponent(style);

                //mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-2.9449549999999998, 104.72977666666665), 12));
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            // Get an instance of the component
            LocationComponent locationComponent = mbMap.getLocationComponent();

            // Set the LocationComponent activation options
            LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions =
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
                            .useDefaultLocationEngine(false)
                            .build();

            // Activate with the LocationComponentActivationOptions object
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);

            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            // Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);

            initLocationEngine();
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set up the LocationEngine and the parameters for querying the device's location
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void initLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this);

        LocationEngineRequest request = new LocationEngineRequest.Builder(DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setPriority(LocationEngineRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setMaxWaitTime(DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME).build();

        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, getMainLooper());
        locationEngine.getLastLocation(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Log.i("LOCATION PERMISSION", "Need user permission");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            mbMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.i("LOCATION PERMISSION", "Location permission not granted");
        }
    }

    private static class LocationCallback implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {

        private final WeakReference<ActivityMapNew> activityWeakReference;

        LocationCallback(ActivityMapNew activity) {
            this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        /**
         * The LocationEngineCallback interface's method which fires when the device's location has changed.
         *
         * @param result the LocationEngineResult object which has the last known location within it.
         */
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
            ActivityMapNew activity = activityWeakReference.get();

            if (activity != null) {
                Location location = result.getLastLocation();

                if (location == null) {
                    return;
                }

                // Create a Toast which displays the new location's coordinates
                Log.i("LOCATION PERMISSION", "New location: " + String.valueOf(result.getLastLocation().getLatitude()) + ", " + String.valueOf(result.getLastLocation().getLongitude()));

                // Pass the new location to the Maps SDK's LocationComponent
                if (activity.mbMap != null && result.getLastLocation() != null) {
                    activity.mbMap.getLocationComponent().forceLocationUpdate(result.getLastLocation());
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * The LocationEngineCallback interface's method which fires when the device's location can't be captured
         *
         * @param exception the exception message
         */
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            ActivityMapNew activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                Log.i("LOCATION PERMISSION", exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Prevent leaks
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates(callback);
        }

        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

I also have test the application without the device location tracker function (only show the map) and it runs well (not crashing). Any similar experience or solution are welcome

Comment: Stop hiding the problem with `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have remove the ``@SuppressLint`` code and the application still crashed